# Read Text after custom word

Tags: c#, winforms, file

My goal is to find a way how to read the text after a word in a File. An example of this is:

Word("Text")

The output would be Text.
Is this achievable?

Comment: "*Is this achievable*" - Sure it is, however you question is lacking a lot of information. So you want to read the complete file after a specific word is found, not just the rest of the line? Does this need to be case sensitive? is this ascii only? Does the result need to be a stream? do you care if you load the whole file into memory?

Comment: Anyway the answer is yes. However the question needs a lot more clarity and focus.

Comment: As `TheGeneral` said, the question lacks a lot of context / information, from your `example` you have said that the output would be the word `Text` but in your first sentence you said `read the text AFTER a word` is this including the word itself? Have you made any attempts yourself at doing this? If so, can you edit your Question and Provide what you have tried and why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Cut your problem into small pieces:

- Read a text file
- Divide the text into a sequence of words
- Skip all words in the sequence until the word that you are looking for
- Use the rest of the sequence of words

**Read the characters in a text file as a sequence of characters**

```
public IEnumerable<char> ReadTextFile(string fileName)
{
    using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        // read the characters one by one until there are no more character (= -1)
        int readResult = textReader.Read();
        while (readResult != -1);
        {
            yield return (char)readResult;
        }
    }
}
```

I decided to return a sequence of char instead of a string. This is a small optimization. If you decide not to read all characters, then not the complete file is read.

**Divide a sequence of characters into a sequence of words.**

The problem is: what is a word? Probably something like: all characters between two white spaces. Something special with the beginning and the end of the sequence.

But how about this: "Hello..World" Are these only the words "Hello" and "World", or is there also an empty word between the two dots? And what if the sequence of characters starts with a dot: ".Hello"?

I'll write this part as an extension method, so you can use it in a LINQ. If you are not familiar with extension methods, consider to read [Extension methods demystified](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/995/extension-methods-csharp).

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ToWords(this IEnumerable<char> source)
{
    string word = String.Empty;
    foreach (char c in source)
    {
        if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        {
            // white space. only a word if already read something
            if (word.Length != 0)
            {
                yield return word
                word = String.Empty;
            }
            // else: the sequence starts with a white space: not a word
        }
        else
        {
            // not a white space: add the character to the word
            word = word + c;
        }
    }

    // if word not empty, then there were characters after the last whitespace
    // like: "Hello World". "Hello" already returned. "World" not yet
    if (word.Length != 0)
        yield return word;
}
```

Consider to optimize the `word = word + c;` part.

**Use LINQ to concatenate what you want**

```
string fileName = ...
string wordToFind = "Hello";
```

// in this example ignore case:
IEqualityComparer stringComparer = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;

```
IEnumerable<string> wordsAfterHello = ReadTextFile(fileName)
    .ToWords()
    .SkipWhile(word => stringComparer.Equals(word, wordToFind);
```

Of course if you plan to use this often, you could write extension methods for this.